# Trying to optimize a *random* query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I need to optimize a procedure in Oracle SQL, mainly using indexes. This is the statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEL_OBS(cuantos number) IS
begin
 FOR I IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM observations ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)WHERE ROWNUM<=cuantos)
LOOP
   DELETE FROM OBSERVATIONS WHERE nplate=i.nplate AND odatetime=i.odatetime; 
     END LOOP; 
end del_obs;
```

My plan was to create an index related with **rownum** since it is what appears to be used to do the deletes. But I don't know if it is going to be worthy. The problem with this procedure is that its randomness causes a lot of *consistent gets*. Can anyone help me with this?? Thanks :)

Note: I cannot change the code, only make improvements afterwards

Comment: The question is, what are you trying to do? Why do you want to delete a random subset of your records?

Comment: @APC it is not my code, I am just ment to improve its execution

Comment: Optimization means producing the same outcome more efficiently. IP is hard to do that when we don't understand what the original code is supposed to do.

Comment: @APC I have a table, and I delete random N rows. That's what the code does. How can I do the deletion more efficiently?

Comment: If you don't know what you are trying to achieve we cannot possibly comment on how to make the implementation more efficient.

Comment: The code is inherently slow. If you cannot rewrite it there's no way to make it faster (given that the access path is the primary key). So, you need to go back to the person who set you this task and explain that it is not possible to improve the performance of the code without rewriting it. Databases are engines, more like mechanical devices not a bag of magic beans. That's what makes them beautiful ( and occasionally frustrating).

Comment: @APC thanks for the advice

Comment: @symcbean I know that what i need to do is delete from a table N different rows. And, given that code above, try to improve its performance with outside tools

Comment: As far as I know, nothing will help that query if you can't change the code. Doing an `ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` is forced to do a table-scan, and no index can improve performance. I would push back on that assignment, it's impossible. It's like, "remodel my kitchen, but you can't remove anything or add anything, or shut off the water, or make any dust." :-)

Comment: The only other options are: (1) DELETE most of the data first, so the remaining data set is smaller and the random sort will be quicker, (2) add a lot more RAM to the server and increase the buffer pool to hold the entire table no matter how large it is, (3) upgrade to a more powerful server with greater CPU and I/O performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ROWID` pseudo-column to filter the columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEL_OBS(
  cuantos number
)
IS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM OBSERVATIONS
  WHERE ROWID IN (
    SELECT rid
    FROM   (
      SELECT ROWID AS rid
      FROM   observations
      ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
    )
    WHERE ROWNUM < cuantos
  );
END del_obs;
```

If you have an index on the table then it can use a index fast full scan:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33165/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id ) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50000;
```

**Query 1**: No Index:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT rid
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROWID AS rid
    FROM   table_name
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
  )
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 10000
)
```

**[Execution Plan](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33165/4/1)**:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name       | Rows  | Bytes  | Cost | Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT               |            |     1 |     24 |  123 | 00:00:02 |
|   1 |   DELETE                       | TABLE_NAME |       |        |      |          |
|   2 |    NESTED LOOPS                |            |     1 |     24 |  123 | 00:00:02 |
|   3 |     VIEW                       | VW_NSO_1   | 10000 | 120000 |  121 | 00:00:02 |
|   4 |      SORT UNIQUE               |            |     1 | 120000 |      |          |
| * 5 |       COUNT STOPKEY            |            |       |        |      |          |
|   6 |        VIEW                    |            | 19974 | 239688 |  121 | 00:00:02 |
| * 7 |         SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY  |            | 19974 | 239688 |  121 | 00:00:02 |
|   8 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL     | TABLE_NAME | 19974 | 239688 |   25 | 00:00:01 |
|   9 |     TABLE ACCESS BY USER ROWID | TABLE_NAME |     1 |     12 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 5 - filter(ROWNUM<=10000)
* 7 - filter(ROWNUM<=10000)
```

**Query 2** Add an index:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT tn__id__pk PRIMARY KEY ( id )
```

**Query 3** With the index:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT rid
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROWID AS rid
    FROM   table_name
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
  )
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 10000
)
```

**[Execution Plan](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33165/4/3)**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name       | Rows | Bytes  | Cost | Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT               |            |    1 |     37 |   13 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   DELETE                       | TABLE_NAME |      |        |      |          |
|   2 |    NESTED LOOPS                |            |    1 |     37 |   13 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |     VIEW                       | VW_NSO_1   | 9968 | 119616 |   11 | 00:00:01 |
|   4 |      SORT UNIQUE               |            |    1 | 119616 |      |          |
| * 5 |       COUNT STOPKEY            |            |      |        |      |          |
|   6 |        VIEW                    |            | 9968 | 119616 |   11 | 00:00:01 |
| * 7 |         SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY  |            | 9968 | 119616 |   11 | 00:00:01 |
|   8 |          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN  | TN__ID__PK | 9968 | 119616 |    9 | 00:00:01 |
|   9 |     TABLE ACCESS BY USER ROWID | TABLE_NAME |    1 |     25 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 5 - filter(ROWNUM<=10000)
* 7 - filter(ROWNUM<=10000)
```

If you cannot do it in single SQL statement using `ROWID` then you can rewrite your existing procedure to use exactly the same queries but use the `FORALL` statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEL_OBS(cuantos number)
IS
  TYPE obs_tab IS TABLE OF observations%ROWTYPE;
begin
  SELECT *
  BULK COLLECT INTO obs_tab
  FROM   (
    SELECT * FROM observations ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
  )
  WHERE ROWNUM<=cuantos;

  FORALL i IN 1 .. obs_tab.COUNT
    DELETE FROM OBSERVATIONS
    WHERE  nplate    = obs_tab(i).nplate
    AND    odatetime = obs_tab(i).odatetime; 
END del_obs;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you definitively need is an index on `OBSERVATIONS` to allow the `DELETE`with an index access.

```
 CREATE INDEX cuantos ON OBSERVATIONS(nplate, odatetime);
```

The execution of the procedure will lead to one `FULL TABLE SCAN`ot the `OBSERVATIONS` table and to one `INDEX ACCESS` *for each deleted record*.

For a limited number deleted recrods it will behave similar as the set `DELETE`proposed in other answer; for larger number of deleted records the elapsed time will linerary scale with the number of deletes.

For a non-trival number of deleted records you must assume that the index is not completely in the buffer pool and lots of disc access will be requried. So you'll end with approximately **100 deleted rows per second**.

In other words **to delete 100K rows it will take ca. 1/4 hour**.

To delete **1M rows you need 2 3/4 of an hour**.

You see while deleting in this scale the first part of the task - the **`FULL SCAN`** of your table is neglectable, it will take few minutes only. The only possibility to get acceptable response time in this case is to switch the logic to a single `DELETE`statement as proposed in other answers.

This behavior is also called the rule: **"Row by Row is Slow by Slow"** (i.e. processing in a loop works fine, but only with a limited number of records).

Comment: I'll try it, but by now I do not understand how that index is gonna help, if that index is created by the DBMS (nplate and odatetime are PK of OBSERVATIONS, sorry I didn't say that)

Comment: Than the index already exists. You may easy verify this showing the DDL script of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a single `delete` statement:

```
delete from observations o
    where (o.nplate, o.odatetime) in (select nplace, odatetime
                                      from (select o2.nplate, o2.odatetime
                                            from observations o2
                                            order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
                                           ) o2
                                      where rownum <= v_cuantos
                                     );
```

This is often faster than executing multiple queries for each row being deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I cannot change the query, it is a given code that we are not allowed to touch. We can only add outside improvements, with indexes or changing PCTFREE and PCTUSED...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. test on MSSQL hopes so it will work also on Oracle. please remarks the status.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEL_OBS(cuantos number) IS
begin

   DELETE OBSERVATIONS  FROM OBSERVATIONS 
   join (select * from  OBSERVATIONS ORDER BY VALUE ) as i on
            nplate=i.nplate AND 
            odatetime=i.odatetime  AND 
            i.ROWNUM<=cuantos;
End DEL_OBS;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I cannot change the code, only make improvements afterwards :S

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that `nplate` and `odatetime` are the primary key of `observations`, then I am guessing the problem is here:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM observations 
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
  WHERE ROWNUM<=cuantos;
```

There is no way to prevent that from performing a full scan of `observations`, plus a lot of sorting if that's a big table.

You need to change the code that runs.  By *far*, the easiest way to change the code is to change the source code and recompile it.

However, there *are* ways to change the code that executes without changing the source code.  Here are two:

(1) Use `DBMS_FGAC` to add a policy that detects whether you are in this procedure and, if so, add a predicate to the `observations` table like this:

```
AND rowid IN 
   ( SELECT obs_sample.rowid 
     FROM observations sample (0.05) obs_sample)
```

(2) Use `DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE` to rewrite your query changing:

```
FROM observations
```

.. to ..

```
FROM observations SAMPLE (0.05)
```

Using the text of your query in the re-write policy should prevent it from affecting other queries against the `observations` table.

Neither of these are easy (at all), but can be worth a try if you are really stuck.